# Is it possible to make an async call and not refresh the session in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have an alert that pops up when the users session is about to expire and when it does expire. The issue is that if multiple tabs are open for the app, multiple alerts will get fired in succession which is very annoying.

I'd like to make a check on the backend for session information before showing an alert. That way if in one tab the session is about to expire (according to the front end), but it's not actually about to expire because you've been operating in another tab, the alert won't display and steal browser focus. Ideally I'd like this to remain as an alert so the first and proper display of the warning does take browser focus.

So is it possible to make a request like this without refreshing the session?

Comment: set a global flag to lock things down. once the first confirm popup appears, it sets the flag and prevents any of the other tabs from popping up the same question.

Comment: You can use localstorage, sessionstorage or cookies to store the flag Marc B proposes.

Comment: You could also do it client side e.g. using `localStorage` (which is shared/persists across tabs).

Comment: You could use another session variable to remember that you've already sent the "about to expire" response, and then if you get another query you send a negative response.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this in JavaScript is silly - it will be really hard to keep the countdown timer in sync with the PHP session.

If you are implementing a hard timeout on the session then you must already be using a custom session handler - so simply implement a variant of that in your Ajax responder which does not lock or write back the session.

OTOH if you're not really implementing a hard session timeout, and you are not already using a custom session handler (which I suspect really is the case). Then just check the timestamp on the session file.